# Switched to HTTPS, should we use URL Removal in Webmaster Tools

Tags: url, https, seo, google-search-console

We recently changed protocol to HTTPS and our google search impressions has plummeted. The old site, with the URL beginning with HTTP is still appearing in google search results even though we have set up our redirects correctly.

Do we go ahead and request URL Removal in Google Webmaster Tools or leave google to do its thing. We are worried that Google might be seeing our old site and penalising our new site for duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you do that the http version will be removed too. Ensure you have set up 301 redirects and be patient.

Comment: Hang on, sorry, I mean we URL remove 'just' the HTTP urls

Comment: Dont use url removal here, it will remove all versions of  your website.